# Dropzone mínimo Archivos a subir

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone

Hola que tal amigos estoy trabajando con la librería **dropzone** y me conseguí con la siguiente dificulta, necesito subir al mismo tiempo exactamente **4 archivos**.

Con la opción **maxfilesexceeded** puedo limitar el máximo de archivos para subir.

Mi pregunta es habrá alguna función que se ejecute cuando no cumpla con el mínimo que quiero..

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos para esto debes usar el init algo asi:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#boton_submit");
        myDropzone = this;
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length >= 4) { 
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
            else {
                alert("No cumple con el requerimiento minimo(4)");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
};

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#my-dropzone');
```

con esto lo que harias es al hacer el submit tu form valida(cuenta) tus archivos que se enviaran y mediante un if determinas ello usando "getQueuedFiles().length" espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Amigo necesito definir la cantidad de archivos mínima a subir,  maxfilesexceeded me indica cuando intento subir mas de la cantidad definida, quiero saber si existe algo parecido para indicar la cantidad mínima a subir, ya busque en la documentación antes de solicitar ayuda.

Comment: Revisalo nuevamente...!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo